# elasticsearch transport client with url path

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch wrapped in tomcat using transport ware is up and running in a cluster of 20 machines on a specific path /essearch. I have load balancer before cluster with dns, so i access elastic search using,
www.dns.com/essearch/

Now, im trying to use the Bulkprocessor to add / update docs in bulk. The elasticsearch TransportClient, only takes in hostname and port and there is no way to specify the path or direct url.

And transport client fails to connect as it doenst fine any nodes on the host and port.

How to specify path in the transport client ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transport Client does not do REST calls. There is no path involved.
So you don't have to set a path.

Note that transport is using 93xx ports but HTTP Rest layer uses 92xx ports.
If you want to use Transport client, then don't forget to use the right port.

Comment: Thank you dadoonet. I changed the transport in yml, and forgot to give the me correct port in transport client. Now it works fine.